# How upload files to AWS only with a few models filtered in django models?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, django-models, storage

I have this code in a models.py of my Django app. I got the default file storage saving my Files on the remote server. But it store ALL the File objects/models to the remote server. Is there any option to set the upload on the remote server AWS only in the models that I want?

````
class Attachment(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=log_att_path)
    log_sender = models.ForeignKey(
        LogSender,
        related_name='attachments',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    attachment_url = models.TextField(default=False)
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>There is a really good and popular package [django-storages](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages) on github. You can use this package to upload your uploaded files to aws. You can use `S3Boto3Storage` from this package to handle your file uploads.</strike>

> Is there any option to set the upload on the remote server AWS only in
>   the models that I want?

You can specify storage class to be used in your file field if you only want to use AWS for specific models/fields like this.

```
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

class Attachment(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=log_att_path, storage=S3Boto3Storage)
    # other stuff
```